# Delphi - modify variable from DLL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to make simple program that sets Edit1.Text to "6" (for example, but with usage of DLL - thats important). Here's the code:
Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  a:integer;

implementation
procedure test; external 'lib.dll' name 'test';

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
test;

Edit1.Text:=Inttostr(a);

end;

end.
```

And the DLL file:

```
library lib;

uses
Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils;

var
a:integer;
procedure test;
begin
  a:=6;
end;

exports
test;
{$R *.res}

begin
end.
```

The problem is, that Edit1.Text is still 0. Can you help me, please?

Comment: If you need to share a variable between .exe and .dll, the standard solution is to use a memory-mapped file.

Comment: @user24 I don't think so. Mapping is for cross process memory sharing. This is in-proc.

Comment: If you launch 2 copies of .exe loading the same .dll you get cross-process. But I am sure you would disagree :)

Comment: @user24 No. That's two processes. But I don't see cross process in the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Building on your original code and adding a few more buttons, here's a demonstration of how you *can* use procedures (or functions if you prefer) and have them play nicely with a **DLL**.

Note that the `name` option is not required unless you wish to *change* the function's name or use overloading - so I've commented it out.

```
implementation
procedure test(var a : integer); external 'lib.dll' {name 'test'};
procedure test2(ptr_a : pinteger); external 'lib.dll';
procedure test3(ptr_a : pinteger); external 'lib.dll';
procedure test4(ptr_a : pinteger = nil); external 'lib.dll';

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test(a);

  Edit1.Text:=Inttostr(a);

end;

procedure TForm14.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test2(@a);

  Edit1.Text:=Inttostr(a);


end;

procedure TForm14.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test3(@a);

  Edit1.Text:=Inttostr(a);

end;

procedure TForm14.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test4(@a);
  test4;

  Edit1.Text:=Inttostr(a);

end;

end.
```

... and the library body ...

```
var
  local_a:integer;
  local_Ptr_a:pinteger;
procedure test(var a : integer);
begin
  a:=6;
end;

procedure test2(ptr_a : pinteger);
begin
  inc(ptr_a^);
end;

procedure test3(ptr_a : pinteger);
begin
  inc(local_a);
  ptr_a^:=local_a;
end;

procedure test4(ptr_a : pinteger = nil);
begin
  if ptr_a = nil then
    inc(local_ptr_a^)
  else
    local_ptr_a := ptr_a;
end;

exports test;
exports test2;
exports test3;
exports test4;
{$R *.res}

begin
  local_a := 4;
end.
```

So - to a little explanation.

First test : using a var-parameter to return a value from a procedure. No problem there.

Second test : pass the *address* of the receiving variable as a *pointer*. I've added a little curl here - incrementing the value for entertainment er,...value.

Third test : This is showing how **local** values owned by the **DLL** can be used. The *local* value is initialised by the assignment of `4` at the end. The procedure itself uses the same mechanism as the second test to return the value from the DLL's local variables to the main routine's variables.

Note that `test3` assigns to the program's variable (1 + the value stored in the DLL's memory, ) hence pressing button3 will actually changes `a`; so pressing buttons 1-2-2-3-2 will use the value from 3 for the last change, not the prior-value-from-2.

Final test: this where we can get a little more clever. It uses the optional-parameters mechanism to vary the detailed operation.

First you eecute the procedure **with** a parameter, being the *address of* (or *pointer to*) a variable of the appropriate type. The procedure stores that address in the DLL's memory area.

Next you can execute the procedure with **no** parameters and it will increment the integer to which the stored pointer is pointing. Purely for convenience, I've established the variable's address on each button-push, but once the address has been stored, it doesn't matter whether that address was set a few microseconds ago or a week, `test4;` will increment the integer value at that address - whatever it is. Set the address using `test4(@b);` then `test4;` will increment `b` - whichever integer was last pointed to when the procedure was executed *with* a parameter.

executing `test4;` without having at sometime prior executed a `test4(@something)` or where *something* is now out-of-scope (like perhaps a local variable in a procedure) is very likely to cause an access violation.

Comment: Downvoted because the proposed solution is C-like and kind of dangerous.

Comment: OP: IOW, because DLLs are normally written in C, it's conventional to add `cdecl;` to the procedure header `procedure test(var a : integer);cdecl; [external filename]` to tell Delphi that the C calling convention, not Delphi's should be used. Delphi is happy provided the executable's convention matches the DLL's but it's a rare and wise C programmer who can accept the concept. Since I've never written in C in anger (only ever as an academic exercise) and have been using Delphi almost exclusively for two decades, it's second nature and automatic in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different variables, one in the DLL and one in the executable. That they are both named `a` is incidental. Setting one has no impact on the other.

Make the DLL export a function that returns the value:

```
function GetValue: Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 6;
end;
```

Import it like this:

```
function GetValue: Integer; stdcall; external dllname;
```

And call it like this:

```
Edit1.Text := IntToStr(GetValue);
```

No doubt the real code will do more than return the value `6` but that's no problem. You can return anything you like. They key point is that you pass the value from the DLL to the host using a function return value.

Answer (score 0):

it works good:

in MainUnit

```
 implementation

  procedure Test(Edit1: TEdit); stdcall; external 'dll_proj.dll';
```

in DLL

```
exports Test;

Procedure Test(Object1: TEdit); stdcall;
var i:integer;
begin
    for i:= 0 to 100 do
      begin
       Object1.Text:= IntToStr(i);
       Application.Processmessages();
       Sleep(100);
    end;
end;
```